# Allow permission dialog in Flutter end-to-end testing?

Tags: testing, flutter, end-to-end

In Flutter end-to-end testing, a permission is to be allowed during the test. `driver.tap(find.text("ALLOW")` does not work. How to click "ALLOW".

[image]

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can grant the permissions before running the test.

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:path/path.dart';

// ...

setUpAll(() async {
  final envVars = Platform.environment;
  final adbPath = join(
    envVars['ANDROID_SDK_ROOT'] ?? envVars['ANDROID_HOME'],
    'platform-tools',
    Platform.isWindows ? 'adb.exe' : 'adb',
  );
  await Process.run(adbPath, [
    'shell',
    'pm',
    'grant',
    'com.example.yourapp', // replace with your app id
    'android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO'
  ]);
  driver = await FlutterDriver.connect();
});
```

Comment: how to grant permission for iOS?

Comment: Hey this is giving me `ProcessException: No such file or directory` error when executing

Comment: @BhupeshVarshney I am getting the same problem ``ProcessException: No such file or directory`` when executing

Comment: @SaeedJassani `xcrun simctl privacy ... grant ...`

Comment: IOS : await Process.run('xcrun', [  'simctl', 'privacy', 'booted', 'grant', 'all',  'your.package.name']);

Comment: ProcessException: Operation not permitted
    Command: xcrun simctl privacy booted grant all

Comment: @vontdeux did you fix granting permissions for ios?

Comment: no i gave up on the idea of doing it on physical ios :S

Answer (score 12):

Other answers will not help you if you are using the latest ***Flutter Integration Testing*** as there we don't require *FlutterDriver* to connect.

So now, you need to add the below code in **test_driver.dart** file where we initialize `integrationDriver()`

```
Future<void> main() async {
    final Map<String, String> envVars = Platform.environment;
    String? adbPath = join(envVars['ANDROID_SDK_ROOT'] ?? envVars['ANDROID_HOME']!,
      'platform-tools',
      Platform.isWindows ? 'adb.exe' : 'adb',
    );
  await Process.run(adbPath , ['shell' ,'pm', 'grant', 'com.example', 'android.permission.CAMERA']);
  await Process.run(adbPath , ['shell' ,'pm', 'grant', 'com.example', 'android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE']);
  await integrationDriver();
}
```

This change is required as `FlutterDriver` makes the connection once you initialized and connect it, but the new flow of integration testing already had a connection, so we need to initialize it before the connection happens.

To run code, use the below command on terminal, as you see for better result I have created two folder,

1. **test_driver:** Contains the driver code mentioned above.
2. **integration_test:** Contains test files.

   ```
   flutter drive --driver=test_driver/test_driver.dart --target=integration_test/my_test.dart
   ```

Comment: Where do I find that `test_driver.dart` file? I don't have one in my project...

Comment: @EmilS.: check the edited answer.

Comment: Thanks, I've figured out by now I have to create it. Kinda sucks that I can no longer use Android Studio for running the tests though.

Comment: What about ios ? How can we grant location permission to ios ? @EmilS. you can still use android studio for running these tests by creating a custom dart command and specifying the driver flag there to match your drive file as well

Comment: what about web?

Answer (score 5):

Try [Patrol](https://github.com/leancodepl/patrol) – it makes cases like yours easy to handle!

1. First, [set up Patrol in your app](https://patrol.leancode.co/native/setup)
2. Install [patrol_cli](https://pub.dev/packages/patrol_cli) – `dart pub global activate patrol_cli`

Once you get the initial setup done, you'll able to write in your tests:

```
await $.native.grantPermissionWhenInUse();
```

To run this test, simply type `patrol test`.

In contrast to the other answers from Susovan, apaatsio and Jitesha, **Patrol works on iOS and Android**.

#### Full code example

```dart
// integration_test/recording_test.dart
import 'package:patrol/patrol.dart';

void main() {
  patrolTest( // patrolTest() instead of testWidgets()
    'records sounds and saves it to internal storage',
    nativeAutomation: true,
    (PatrolTester $) async { // PatrolTester instead of WidgetTester
      await $.pumpWidget(YourAppWidget()); // replace with your own

      await $('Record').tap(); // Patrol's custom finders syntax (optional)
      await $.native.grantPermissionWhenInUse();
    },
  );
}
```

To run it:

```
patrol test
```

#### More about Patrol

[Patrol is available on pub.dev](https://pub.dev/packages/patrol) and [has extensive documentation](https://patrol.leancode.co). [Here's a succinct overview](https://patrol.leancode.co/native/feature-parity) of the native features it supports.

Apart from interacting with native features, Patrol has:

- [custom widget finders](https://patrol.leancode.co/finders/overview), which make tests much shorter and more robust
- [`patrol develop` command, which supports Hot Restart](https://patrol.leancode.co/cli-commands/develop) in integration tests, speeding up development cycles
- Support for [Firebase Test Lab](https://patrol.leancode.co/ci/firebase-test-lab) & more!

Answer (score 2):

for me above code is **not working** don't know why

**then i'm tried with below code and its working**

```
setUpAll(() async {

      await Process.run('add_adb_path/adb.exe' , ['shell' ,'pm', 'grant', 'add_app_package_name', 'android.permission.ACCESS_MEDIA_LOCATION']);
      await Process.run('add_adb_path/adb.exe' , ['shell' ,'pm', 'grant', 'add_app_package_name', 'android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE']);
      await Process.run('add_adb_path/adb.exe' , ['shell' ,'pm', 'grant', 'add_app_package_name', 'android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE']);


      driver = await FlutterDriver.connect();
    });
```