# how can i click on allow pop up message to grant permission by integration test package in flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, automated-tests, integration-testing, android-permissions

i wrote an integration test by `integration test` package with `flutter`.
but my app need to grant location permission, and it show native pop up message to allow or deny
i want to click on allow button by automated test using `integration test package`

i tried to search about this issue but it doesn't exist
this image for message :
https://i.stack.imgur.com/HmRBS.jpg

can i click on native element by this kind of test ?

Answer (score 1):

No you can't. Integration tests can't interact with native components or other applications.

Only way to click through it is to do it manually.
Or allow it beforehand. Solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53641294/allow-permission-dialog-in-flutter-end-to-end-testing)