# Authorize camera access in integration testing with flutter integration_test package

Tags: integration-testing, android-permissions, flutter-test, permission-denied

I want to test Add Picture (using camera) feature for my app using integration_test package for app. When app tries to open a camera it asks for camera permission and I could not find a way to tap allow permission as its a system dialog.

I am looking for two solution.

1 - Find a way to control System dialog so I can tap allow button using Widget Tester.
2 - I want to set a all permission when I start the app for Testing. Please note that I want to do only for testing.

Answer (score 1):

as of now integration test can't interact with native popups and other application.

But solution to this problem was given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53641294/allow-permission-dialog-in-flutter-end-to-end-testing)

Comment: i dont think this solution works for real physical devices right?

Comment: It does, popups won't show up and test will continue just fine.

Comment: on iphones (iOS) too? or just android?

Comment: I've only tested on androids, so can't say for IOS.

Comment: ahh yes, didnt work for IOS for me. it will only work on simulator phones.